# CefSharp: How to allow/disable Camera/Microphone on runtime?

Tags: winforms, chromium, cefsharp

In my WinForms App I have a number of CefSharp browser windows.

In one of these windows resp. forms Cam & Mic should be always allowed, without asking for permission because in this window I know all websites displayed here - it's all safe.

In other windows potentially "the internet" is displayed. Here Mic & Cam MUST be switched off for security reasons.

But there's no such configuration at runtime, unfortunately, and there are by now only 4 votes for set-permission-at-runtime Feature Request (https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2582/allow-run-time-handling-of-media-access)

However, I urgently need a solution to effectively close the potential security leak.

Does anyone have any other idea or trick for how to disable Mic & Cam access effectively?

Comment: There is a PR which adds support,  you could build a custom version of CEF and add the relevant classes to CefSharp https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/pull-requests/323/media-access-handler/diff

Comment: I'm terms of tricks you can probably execute some JavaScript to override the media access methods and return permission denied, I haven't tested, shouldn't be too hard.